# Input mask issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, input-mask, jquery-inputmask

So, I have an input mask that I'm having issues with.

The country variables:

```
<?php

    $countryList = array("Australia", "Canada", "France",  "Italy", "Spain", "U.K.", "U.S.A.", "Other")
?>
```

These are my inputs:

```
<select class="form-control" id="country" name="country" onchange="show(this)">
      <?php foreach($countryList as $aCountry){ ?>
     
    <option value="<?=$aCountry?>"><?=$aCountry?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select> 

<input class="form-control form-control-lg text-center" type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone#" value="" required>
```

I'm including these libraries:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/5.0.5/jquery.inputmask.min.js"></script>
```

When I use it like this, it works fine:

```
$('#phone').inputmask("(999) 999 9999");
```

When I do this, it also works fine:

```
var num = "(999) 999-9999"
            
mask(num);

function mask(n){  
        
$('#phone').inputmask(n);

            }
```

But for whatever reason, this will not work:

```
$('#country').change(function(){
            
  $("#country").each(function () {
    var className = $(this).val();
      if(className == "U.S.A."){
          var number = "(999) 999 9999";
        mask(number); 
      }
    
  });

 function mask(n){  
            
    $('#phone').inputmask(n);
    
                }
```

If I stick an alert function in there, it works fine when I change the dropdown. Why won't the mask?

**update

I updated the code (per comments) to:

```
$('#country').change(function(){ var className = $(this).val() {
    var className = $(this).val();
    if (className == "U.S.A.") {
      var number = "9 999 9999";
      mask(number);
    }
  });
});

function mask(n) {
  $('#phone').inputmask(n);
}
```

However, it's still not working.

Comment: `$('#country').each` <= this is a code smell.  An id lookup will only ever return just one element

Comment: I made your code runnable.... they both seem to run fine. Please alter it if it is any different.

Comment: @epascarello adding content to a question isn't really the purpose of a mod  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code

Comment: @epascarello I'm still getting the same result.  I added a few more details to my original question.

Comment: Well for one thing, the code should be `$('#country').change(function(){ var className = $(this).val();` without the each since it is just one element.

Comment: @epascarello I updated the code per your comment, but it's still not working.

Comment: I have no idea what to tell you because I ran it just fine. Unless you can make a demo with the problem it is hard to help. (and your edit has a syntax errors)

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured it out.  I was calling the query library twice.